# Can you take the Magic Initiate feat more than once?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats

One of my players, a Warlock, wants to learn a few Cleric spells but not multiclass into Cleric, so he took the magic initiate feat. He just posed the question about taking the feat again at a later level and I'm not sure if there's anything that disallows it.

If there is something in there that says you can't take the feat more than once, would I be breaking anything by allowing him to?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## By RAW, no.

The Feats description mentions

> You can take each feat only once, unless the feat’s description says otherwise.

The **Magic Initiate** feat does not say it can be taken twice.

### Would it be game-breaking? I don't think so.

You are trading an ASI upgrade to learn a few cantrips and 2 1st-level spells. It seems to me to actually be a poor mechanical decision.

That being said, I would suggest him multi-classing into Cleric for a level instead of taking this feat twice as a homebrew rule. I don't know your motives for not wanting to do it, of course, so this may not be applicable to your group.

Comment: Personally I'm not entirely sure why the player wants to do this either, but I don't want to say no if they feel it's how they want to progress. I totally agree however!

Comment: Ask them for their motives and suggest an alternative. If they still want to go through with it, then as long as they are satisfied, let them. It's all about having fun

Comment: I would recommend removing the word "wasting" as it's entirely subjective. A fighter taking this feat may be doing so strictly for an on demand ranged weapon that bypasses non-magical damage resistance and immunity, making it worth an ASI sacrifice to that player. As for why somebody would take the feat over a 1 level dip, perhaps they don't want to sacrifice all the advantages that NOT taking a multi-class grants.

Comment: Seconding what @LinoFrankCiaralli said. Falling 1 level behind in spell progression can be a big deal for spellcasters. Additionally, there's a good number of spells that pack a lot of utility into a single casting. Mage Armor and Goodberry will last you a whole adventuring day. Find Familiar is very desirable both RP-wise and mechanically to many players (e.g. a Cleric with a familiar can deliver Cure Wounds from a distance, or grant himself advantage for Guiding Bolt).

Comment: Plus any melee class taking Eldritch Blast as a cantrip can now effect creatures in the ethereal plane (force damage) as well as having a ranged attack, on demand, that can't be taken away (without magic). That alone is worth it to me.

Comment: @LinoFrankCiaralli [Force damage doesn't reach into the Ethereal Plane](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/756182825259241473).

Comment: @Doval - Thought about it some. I'm fine with that not affecting the ethereal plane if you're on the material plane firing it. So long as that goes both ways then.

Comment: I agree that the two feats are wasted. Taking one level of Cleric gives you everything valuable they would, and so much more: __Armor__ proficiency (possibly Heavy), __Shield__ proficieny, you can __change__ the Cleric spells you get after every long rest, you can cast these spells from __Warlock spell slots__ (so upcasting is an option now), __Divine Domain__, AND two feats that are actually useful. The cost you pay is minor: must have 13 Wis, you have 1 less cleric cantrip, and one level behing a single class Warlock, but __not__ with Eldritch Blast, as is scales with character level.

Comment: @LinoFrankCiaralli, It is not a Cleric taking Warlock cantrips, but the other way around.

Comment: Thats really not my point Andras. The point is that just because you dont consider a feat useful, doesnt mean others wouldnt.

Answer (score 3):

**Strictly:** No, unless stated.

**As DM:** Yes, if you want to allow it.

You cannot select a feat again, unless specifically stated.
As reference: PHB 166, Elemental Adept:

> Prerequisite: The ability to cast at least one spell
>   When you gain this feat, choose one o f the following
>   damage types: acid, cold, fire, lightning, or thunder.
>   Spells you cast ignore resistance to damage o f the
>   chosen type. In addition, when you roll damage for a
>   spell you cast that deals damage of that type, you can
>   treat any 1 on a damage die as a 2.
>   **You can select this feat multiple times**. Each time
>   you do so, you must choose a different damage type.